# Play 2.1: Await result from enumerator

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I'm working on testing my WebSocket code in Play Framework 2.1. My approach is to get the iterator/enumerator pair that are used for the actual web socket, and just test pushing data in and pulling data out.

Unfortunately, I just cannot figure out how to get data out of an Enumerator. Right now my code looks roughly like this:

```
val (in, out) = createClient(FakeRequest("GET", "/myendpoint"))

in.feed(Input.El("My input here"))
in.feed(Input.EOF)

//no idea how to get data from "out"
```

As far as I can tell, the only way to get data out of an enumerator is through an iteratee. But I can't figure out how to just wait until I get the full list of strings coming out of the enumerator. What I want is a `List[String]`, not a `Future[Iteratee[A,String]]` or an `Expectable[Iteratee[String]]` or yet another `Iteratee[String]`. The documentation is confusing at best.

How do I do that?

Comment: Could you add the (simplified) contents of the `createClient` method?

Answer (score -1):

You can consume an `Enumerator` like this:

```
  val out = Enumerator("one", "two")

  val consumer = Iteratee.getChunks[String]

  val appliedEnumeratorFuture = out.apply(consumer)

  val appliedEnumerator = Await.result(appliedEnumeratorFuture, 1.seconds)

  val result = Await.result(appliedEnumerator.run, 1.seconds)

  println(result) // List("one", "two")
```

Note that you need to await a `Future` twice because `Enumerator` and `Iteratee` control the speed of respectively producing and consuming values.

A more elaborate example for an `Iteratee` -> `Enumerator` chain where feeding the `Iteratee` results in the `Enumerator` producing values:

```
  // create an enumerator to which messages can be pushed
  // using a channel
  val (out, channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[String]

  // create the input stream. When it receives an string, it
  // will push the info into the channel
  val in =
    Iteratee.foreach[String] { s =>
      channel.push(s)
    }.map(_ => channel.eofAndEnd())

  // Instead of using the complex `feed` method, we just create
  // an enumerator that we can use to feed the input stream
  val producer = Enumerator("one", "two").andThen(Enumerator.eof)

  // Apply the input stream to the producer (feed the input stream)
  val producedElementsFuture = producer.apply(in)

  // Create a consumer for the output stream
  val consumer = Iteratee.getChunks[String]

  // Apply the consumer to the output stream (consume the output stream)
  val consumedOutputStreamFuture = out.apply(consumer)

  // Await the construction of the input stream chain
  Await.result(producedElementsFuture, 1.second)
  // Await the construction of the output stream chain
  val consumedOutputStream = Await.result(consumedOutputStreamFuture, 1.second)
  // Await consuming the output stream
  val result = Await.result(consumedOutputStream.run, 1.second)

  println(result) // List("one", "two")
```